# Google Workflow Problem with Retry Predicate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to learn Google Workflow retry mechanism. My actual requirement is to request a `http.get` and will get a text response and i have to check that text and if it doesn't satisfy my condition, it should retry after say 10 seconds.

So to try it out, I made below example and from the docs learnt, standard retry would not fit my requirement as its based on http return codes so, went for custom predicate and defined a sub-workflow. And learnt I cannot pass any arguments to this sub-workflow, tried to `raise` error as per one example. But, this doesn't show any error in the code window but fails during runtime

```yaml
main:
  steps:
    - first_step:
        try:
            steps:
                - getCurrentDay:
                    call: http.get
                    args:
                        url: https://us-central1-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
                    result: currentDateTime
                - setFromCallResult:
                    assign:
                        - dayName: ${currentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
                - whatIsToday:
                    call: sys.log
                    args:
                        data: ${dayName + " is actually a day"}
                        severity: "INFO" # Optional
                - callRetry:
                    switch:
                        - condition: ${dayName == "Thursday"}
                          raise: ${dayName}                                    
        retry:
            predicate: ${my_own_predicate}
            max_retries: 5
            backoff:
                initial_delay: 2
                max_delay: 60
                multiplier: 1
    - last_step:
        return: "OK"

my_own_predicate:
  params: [dayName]
  steps:
    - checkRetryCond:
        switch:
            - condition: ${dayName == "Thursday"}
              return: False
    - otherwise:
        return: True
```

Below is the error:

```yaml
RuntimeError: "Thursday"
in step "first_step", routine "main", line: 24
"Thursday"
```

Line number 24 is

```yaml
            predicate: ${my_own_predicate}
```

At this point I cannot figure out what the issue is

Comment: Have you tried to invert the conditionals on lines 39 and 41 in `my_own_predicate`, as in this [example](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/samples/workflows-error-retry-predicate)

Comment: Flipping the conditions does work, it does retries but how to stop the retries and proceed to next step. If the conditions succeed. Still get the runtime error RuntimeError: "Tuesday"

Answer (score 4):

### Summary

The issue with the code is the logic. It is stuck in an infinite loop when it has to retry until it reaches the `max_retry`. This is due to the logic that is in the *retry* that never changes, so the same result occurs in every retry. There needs to be a logic that will exit this, otherwise you will get the error output.

---

### To break down the problem:

#### Let’s say that today is *“Thursday”*  to see what happens:

> `getCurrentDay` gets the date (i.e. "Thursday")
>
> `setFromCallResult` creates a parameter `dayName="Thursday"`
>
> `whatIsToday` logs the dayName parameter
>
> `callRetry` checks if `dayName != “Thursday”`. Since that is false, it does not raise the error and goes to `last_step` and “Ok” is returned

#### Now let's say that today is *"Friday"*

> `getCurrentDay` gets the date (i.e. "Friday")
>
> `setFromCallResult` creates a parameter `dayName="Friday"`
>
> `whatIsToday` logs the `dayName` parameter
>
> `callRetry` checks if `dayName == "Friday"`. Since that is false, it raises an error with the `dayName` parameter
>
> Enters the *retry* which calls the `my_own_predicate` subworkflow
>
> `my_own_predicate` starts with `dayName` parameter equal to `“Friday”`. Since the condition is also if `dayName != “Thursday”` it returns False, meaning *not to retry* and the raised error is then returned.

You need to handle the raised error or have it retry in a way that has a different result.

As in the example. an except block is needed to catch the raised error and return a proper response.

> **TL;DR** The logic that is retried (custom predicate) needs to be changed or you will get the same result. Raised errors need to be handled with except block.

### Example

```yaml
main:
  steps:
    - first_step:
        try:
            steps:
                - getCurrentDay:
                    #ideally, this function should be dynamic and return a different response each time (which it will for the customer)
                    call: http.get
                    args:
                        #this function is purely for demo purposes
                        url: https://us-central1-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
                    result: currentDateTime
                - setFromCallResult:
                    assign:
                        - dayName: ${currentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
                - whatIsToday:
                    call: sys.log
                    args:
                        data: ${dayName + " is actually a day"}
                        severity: "INFO" # Optional
                - callRetry:
                    switch:
                        #does it match the text?
                        - condition: ${dayName != "Thursday"}
                        #it does not match, we need to retry
                          raise: ${dayName}                                   
        retry:
            predicate: ${my_own_predicate}
            max_retries: 5
            backoff:
                initial_delay: 2
                max_delay: 60
                multiplier: 1
        except:
            #retries did not get the desired result, fail gracefully
            return: "hit 5 retries and did not get Thursday" 
    - last_step:
        #it enters this step only when dayName == "Thursday"
        return: "It's Thursday"
my_own_predicate:
  params: [dayName]
  steps:
    - logRetry:
        call: sys.log
        args:
            data: ${dayName + " is not the desired value, check to see if we need to retry"}
            severity: "INFO" # Optional
    - checkRetryCond:
        switch:
            - condition: ${dayName == "Thursday"} #since the response is what we need, there is no need to retry
              return: False #stop retrying
    - otherwise:
        return: True # do retry
```

Answer (score 0):

I could'nt resove the retry issues. So, i went to proceed with normal without retry appraoch. Its a bit lengthy, its the only workaround i have right now.

1. In the main, i am assigning the url, retry times and sleep_seconds
2. I am calling the function getDate and passing the above values.
3. In getDay

   - Display the arguments
   - Going into a loop which looks like a nested steps
   - init: does the initialization
   - check_condition: checks the retry condition. If OK executes process: otherwise fail:
   - process: calls the http.get
   - showResult: Shows the received results
   - verifyResult: processes the received results. If looks good executes success:
   - iterate: is a nested steps - does the sleep and decreases the retry count and goes back to check_condition:
   - Further down i have success: fail: and exit_fn:

```
main:
  params: [today] 
  steps:
    - initValues1:
        assign:
            - inParm: 
                url: https://us-central1-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
                retry: 5
                sleep_seconds: 10
                day: ${today.day}
    - callFunction1:
        call: getDay
        args:
            inParm: ${inParm}
        result: retData
    - showLog1:
        call: sys.log
        args:
            data: ${"Returned results are, today is "+ retData.dayName + " and it was expected to be " + today.day + "; Go-NoGo Decision=" + retData.gonogo}
            severity: "INFO" # Optional
    - verifyRetry1:
        switch:
            - condition: ${retData.gonogo == "NOGO"}
              next: exit_wf
        next: process2
    - process2:
        call: sys.log
        args:
            data: ${"Doing Process Two"}
            severity: "INFO" # Optional
    - exit_wf:
        return: ${retData}

getDay:
  params: [inParm]
  steps:
    - displayParms:
        call: sys.log
        args:
            data: ${inParm}
            severity: "INFO"
    - looping:
        steps:      
            - init: 
                assign:
                    - retry: ${inParm.retry}
                    - sleep_seconds: ${inParm.sleep_seconds}
            - check_condition:
                switch:
                - condition: ${retry > 0}
                  next: process
                next: fail
            - process:
                call: http.get
                args:
                    url: ${inParm.url}
                result: currentDateTime
            - showResult:
                call: sys.log
                args:
                    data: ${"Retry=" + string(retry) + "; Today is = " + currentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
                    severity: "INFO"
            - verifyResult:
                switch:
                - condition: ${currentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek == inParm.day}
                  next: success
                next: iterate
            - iterate:
                steps:
                    - sleep:
                        call: sys.sleep
                        args:
                            seconds: ${sleep_seconds}
                    - decrement_retry:
                        assign:
                            - retry: ${retry-1}
                        next: check_condition
    - success:
        assign:
            - retData:
                gonogo: GO
                dayName: ${currentDateTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
        next: exit_fn
    - fail:
        assign:
            - retData:
                gonogo: NOGO
                dayName: SKIP
                retry: ${retry}
        next: exit_fn
    - exit_fn:
        return: ${retData}
```